# Using Jersey/JAX-RS should a prefix match on a Resource Class prevent Subresources on another Resource matching?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I'm trying to make a resource class that handles similar functionality under a variety of other prefixes ie "/bar/{id}/foo" "/fizz/{id}/foo" because grouping the methods that way made more sense to me.

So I have a Resource class that's essentially:

```
@Path("/")
public class FooResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/foo")
    public String foo()
    {
        return "Hello Foo";
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/bar/stuff/foo")
    public String bar()
    {
        return ("Hello nested foo.");
    }
}
```

When it's registered by itself in the Dropwizard application, it works just fine (ie gives me the responses as expected). However, if another Resource class is registered with a common prefix such as

```
@Path("/bar")
public class BarResource
{
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public String bar(@PathParam("id") String id)
    {
        return "Hello:" + id;
    }
}
```

Then the subresources in FooResource never get matched leading to 404s. Yet in both cases Dropwizard lists the FooResource SubResources as found paths.

```
GET     /bar/stuff/foo (FooResource)
GET     /bar/{id} (BarResource)
GET     /foo (FooResource)
```

Reading section 3.7.2 of the JAX-RS specification,

> JSR-339 Java™ API for RESTful Web Services (“Specification”)
>
> Version: 2.0
>
> Status: Final Release
>
> Release: May 22, 2013

this doesn't *look* like the way it's supposed to work. As bar resource doesn't have a subresource that matches /bar/stuff/foo. Am I missing something about how this is supposed to work? Obviously I can just refactor my code, but I did prefer this organization scheme.

Answer (score 0):

as I misunderstood your question, I gave it another go on debugging. I read the relevant section you pointed out. First I will try to outline what is supposed to happen and then what is happening inside jersey:

1. All Resources on class level get a regex that is used to match the path, this means for you:

`@Path("/")` becomes `(/.*)?`

`@Path("bar")` becomes `/bar(/.*)?`

How to do the paths is described in `3.7.3`. I know these to be correct because I grabbed them out of the debugger :)

This is really all we need to see what is happening here. Now that we have our regex, the algorithm described in the JSR dictates this behaviour in 3.7.2.1.(e):

> Sort E using the number of literal characters in each member as the
>   primary key (descending order), the number of capturing groups as a
>   secondary key (descending order) and the number of capturing groups
>   with non-default regular expressions (i.e. not ‘([ˆ/]+?)’) as the
>   tertiary key (descending order)

Where the literal characters are:

> Here, literal characters means those not resulting from template
>   variable substitution.

Now, looking in `PathMatchingRouter` we can find that in the `apply` method we are stepping through the possible `Routes` and picking the first that matches. This is also described here as found by you: 2.7.2.1.(f)

> Set Rmatch to be the first member of E and set U to be the value of
>   the final capturing group of Rmatch when matched against U. Let C 0 be
>   the set of classes Z such that R(TZ) = Rmatch. By definition, all root
>   resource classes in C 0 must be annotated with the same URI path
>   template modulo variable names.

The problem is, as you have pointed out correctly:

> By definition, all root
>   resource classes in C 0 must be annotated with the same URI path
>   template modulo variable names.

We have broken this by having two different root paths. This will naturally always match the first one and therefore can only match one.

Question (from my side): Are we not matching the wrong resource though? From the JSR, I believe that the matching resources should have been sorted the other way around, matching your `/bar/stuff/foo` every time, because the root resource path is shorter than the other. (Not at all sure about that)

I have tried that by using the debugger and unmatching the first (shorter) resource, which has the result I pointed out, the other resource being matched every time.

But, in short, this seems to be correct (apart from the above question)

What happens in Jersey (as additional info):

Jersey's resource model breaks down the resources and methods into stages of routing.

Stage1 -> match all routing with the path

Stage2 -> base on Stage1 match all methods that would have matched Stage1 too

That means that Stage1 is not a resource class that is matched but rather just a high-level routing phase that, as routing children, has all paths that can possibly match the root (which is why it works if the class-level variable is the same).

In case you are looking to debug this yourself (which was actually a bit of fun too), you can have a look into these internal classes (breakpoint in apply):

- MatchResultInitializerRouter
- SubResourceLocatorRouter
- MethodSelectingRouter
- PathMatchingRouter

I found this as additional info as well:

https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/quick-peek-at-jax-rs-request-to-method-matching/

And for completeness, here is the JSR in question:

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf

I hope this answers the (somewhat self-answered) question in a bit of detail. Again, my apologies for getting the question wrong in the beginning.

Comment: I've reread the algorithm, and figured out my mistake but your explanation doesn't seem quite correct. Two Resources can be matched, but only if they are "annotated with the same URI path template modulo variable names" and rather than moving on to the next resource from step 1 of the algorithm it terminates at 2(e)

Comment: @cacsar thank you for pointing that out. I didn't have time to go debug all the way down but thought it might help anyway :) Glad you figured it out. I will try and correct my answer Monday :)

Comment: Do you have a source, I am looking up some info as well, but I read your statement the same I read mine: `You can bypass that by making both resources sub-resources. That means, move the path annotation from the class level to the method level and it should work.` By having the resources on the same path, they become the root resource (as in one object defined as root that can be matched on "/bar") while all methods on both resources become sub-resources relative to the root. But I might be wrong on that

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it's JSR-339. It's possible that the difference we're having is simply differences in how it's read. I'd always known *how* to make it work but not the *why* of why it didn't. What still seems off to me about your answer is that multiple "Root Resource classes" (spec term) can be matched and are searched.

Comment: @cacsar you are right. I misread the question. I gave it another try, but you have already answered the question yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I had indeed misread the algorithm (section 3.7.2 of the JaxRS spec)in the spec while confused. A summary of the portions of the algorithm that shows where I went wrong is:

1. Find the best match (or matches) for the Resource. Consider only these Resource classes. "By definition, all root resource classes in C' must be annotated with the same URI path template modulo variable names."
2. If you can't find a match in C' then throw a 404.

I had thought it would return to step 1 and find the next best match.

The closest it looks like I'd be able to come to organizing my code this way would be to have a separate resource for each subpath to get the needed priority level.

Answer (score 0):

building on your own answer and that statement:

> The closest it looks like I'd be able to come to organizing my code
>   this way would be to have a separate resource for each subpath to get
>   the needed priority level.

I wanted to add sub-resource locators as an options for completeness. You can organise your code this way:

```
public class Application extends io.dropwizard.Application<Configuration>{

    @Override
    public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        environment.jersey().register(SubResourceTest.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Application().run("server", "/home/artur/dev/repo/sandbox/src/main/resources/config/test.yaml");
    }

    public static class MyResourceBean {
        String test;
    }

    @Path("/bar")
    public static class SubResourceTest {

        @Path("bar")
        public SubR test() {
            return new SubR();
        }
    }

    @Path("")
    public static class SubR {

        @GET
        @Path("foo/stuff")
        public String fooStuff() {
            return "fooStuff";
        }

        @GET
        @Path("{id}")
        public String generic(@PathParam("id") String id) {
            return id;
        }

    }
}
```

Now `SubResourceTest` returns a sub-resource that serves both of the paths you want.

Or, to make it even more wonky :), if you absolutely MUST split the resource classes, this example for resources also works for me (not that this is pretty, it is just a bit of playing around):

```
@Path("/bar")
    public static class SubResourceTest {

        @Path("bar/{string}")
        public Object test(@PathParam("string") String s) {
            if(s.equals("foo")) {
                return new SubRStuff();
            }
            return new SubRGeneric(s);
        }
    }

    public static class SubRStuff {

        @GET
        @Path("stuff")
        public String fooStuff() {
            return "fooStuff";
        }

    }

    public static class SubRGeneric {

        private String id;

        public SubRGeneric(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @GET
        public String generic() {
            return id;
        }
    }
```

Essentially, the bar resource checks for the path programatically (is it `foo`?) and then returns the appropriate sub-resource handling the problem. In case it is the generic one, it simply passes on the String. This works for me doing:

```
artur@pandaadb:~$ curl localhost:9085/api/bar/bar/HelloWorld
HelloWorld
artur@pandaadb:~$ curl localhost:9085/api/bar/bar/foo/stuff
fooStuff
curl localhost:9085/api/bar/bar/myNameIsArtur
myNameIsArtur
```

Obviously this might not be what you are looking for, but it is an alternative and maybe it fits your use case :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Path("/")
public class FooResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/foo")
    public String foo()
    {
        return "Hello Foo";
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/bar/stuff/foo")
    public String bar()
    {
        return ("Hello nested foo.");
    }
}

@Path("/")
public class BarResource
{
    @GET
    @Path("/bar/{id}")
    public String bar(@PathParam("id") String id)
    {
        return "Hello:" + id;
    }
}
```

if you change your code like this, it will work as i tried.